# Getting the number of affected rows including those not changed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am doing a statement like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET x = 1 WHERE y = 2
```

And using `rowCount` from PDO to get whether or not the row was changed (`y` is unique, so either none or one row is updated). This isn't what I need though, since, using the previous example, if `x` is *already* 1, then `rowCount()` will be 0 since no row was changed from its previous value. What I really need is to know whether a row matched the `WHERE` clause.

Is there a way to do that without doing another query?

Comment: `select count(*) where y=2`

Comment: No, there is no other way. It’s not the purpose of an UPDATE statement to do what SELECT statements are _for_.

Comment: @MarcB how do you combine them into one query? (that was one of the conditions of the question)

Comment: @CBroe so there is no way to get MySQL to do **LESS** work? Because checking if the new value = the old value is more work than I want it to do.

Comment: You can't. getting affectedrows back from an update is a side effect/metadata. You cannot use an 'update' to get back general purpose data, that's why there's select queries.

Comment: @MarcB If that's true then it's silly because it makes you repeat work you already had to do once before.

Comment: maybe silly, but consider the work necessary to do both a select and an update at the same time on the same table. It's a literal equivalent of trying to change a shoe while standing in it.

Comment: @MarcB You have to find which rows to change before you change them anyway, so there is an implicit SELECT in an UPDATE. And also I just found `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` which does what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that PDO has just the thing: `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS`.

Answer (score -1):

i think adding a where x != 1 should solve the problem, if you add it this row won't be affected, so the rowCount() will return only the rows changed.

Comment: No, it won't be affected and rowCount will be 0. I need to get the information "one matched row" even if x is already 1 (whether that's by rowCount or another function is immaterial).